# WPF Select Input Audio and set Output device Audio

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I'm trying to create a WPF application that allows me to select an audio source, which comes from a video, microphone, input audio, or other device connected to the PC and send it to an audio device that is connected to the PC.
To test, I used `MediaElement` but it only lets me select a video, I can't select another source, and I can't select the output device.
 I tried to see NAudio and also Unosquare.FFME but I couldn't figure out how to solve the problem.
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

With NAudio you can do that easily.

You can get all available devices on computer by using the class `MMDeviceEnumerator`. Call the static function named `EnumerateAudioEndPoints`.

Example:

```
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;

using (var devices = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
{
    foreach (var device in devices.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active))
    {
        // do something with device
    }
}
```

The `DataFlow` enum you can choise between input or output devices.